# Button visible and invisible

Tags: android

I am new in android app development. 
I am searching an example like bellow:

There is a checkbox and two buttons named `btn1` and `btn2`.
Logic should be when user will checked on the checkbox then `btn2` will visible and `btn1` will invisible.

In my XML file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_provider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:id="@+id/input_chk_provider"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:duplicateParentState="false"
                android:text="@string/user_type_provider" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_sing_up"
            android:background="@color/ic_launcher_background"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_provider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btn_provider_dtl"
            android:background="@color/ic_launcher_background"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Actually I need to know to handle this issue considering my provides xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML use `android:visibility="invisible"` to set the visibility of the buttons.

In the code, get your views with `findViewById()`

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check1);
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton button, boolean isChecked) {
      if(isChecked){ 
         yourButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } else {
         yourButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      } 
   }

});
```

Use the method `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to change the visibility.

There are 3 states:

```
View.GONE
View.VISIBLE
View.INVISIBLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having the code...
You'll need a `OnCheckedChangeListener` for the Checkbox so you can adjust the button visibility when it's checked/unchecked.
Something like:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) { 
                btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox has OnCheckedChangeListener() method which will give you the state of the checkbox. Based on the state of the Checkbox you can use Button1.setVisibility(true/false); to show/hide the button.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/input_chk_provider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:onClick="itemClicked"
        android:duplicateParentState="false" />

    public void itemClicked(View v) {
            //code to check if this checkbox is checked!
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)v;
            if(checkBox.isChecked()==true){
                bt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bt2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else if(checkBox.isChecked()==false){
                bt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
```